# How to work with yearmonth from tsibble in ggplot and dplyr

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tsibble

Working example:

```
library(fpp3)

Data <- aus_retail %>%
  filter(State == "Western Australia",
         Industry == "Takeaway food services")

autoplot(Data) + xlim()
```

How would I go about doing something like limit the x axis or filter the data such that only dates after 2000 are stored? Not sure how to work with tsibble's yearmonth variables.

Thanks!

Comment: From which package is `aus_retail` dataset from? I can't find it in `fpp3`.

Comment: @RonakShah it should be in `tsibbledata`. My version of `fpp3` is 0.4.0 and my version of `tsibbledata` is 0.3.0 if that helps.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `year` function from `lubridate` to extract year from `yearmonth` object and keep data only after 2000.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

tsibbledata::aus_retail %>%
  filter(State == "Western Australia",
         Industry == "Takeaway food services") %>%
  filter(year(Month) >= 2000)

#   State             Industry               `Series ID`    Month Turnover
#   <chr>             <chr>                  <chr>          <mth>    <dbl>
# 1 Western Australia Takeaway food services A3349435A   2000 Jan     61  
# 2 Western Australia Takeaway food services A3349435A   2000 Feb     56  
# 3 Western Australia Takeaway food services A3349435A   2000 Mar     61.1
# 4 Western Australia Takeaway food services A3349435A   2000 Apr     64.2
# 5 Western Australia Takeaway food services A3349435A   2000 May     65.7
# 6 Western Australia Takeaway food services A3349435A   2000 Jun     64.9
# 7 Western Australia Takeaway food services A3349435A   2000 Jul     62.6
# 8 Western Australia Takeaway food services A3349435A   2000 Aug     62.8
# 9 Western Australia Takeaway food services A3349435A   2000 Sep     62.1
#10 Western Australia Takeaway food services A3349435A   2000 Oct     66.6
# … with 218 more rows
```